# How to do a parallel_reduce in TBB to append std::vector?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp, reduce, tbb

I've defined this reduction in OpenMP:

```
std::vector<FindAffineShapeArgs> v;
#pragma omp declare reduction(mergeFindAffineShapeArgs : std::vector<FindAffineShapeArgs> : omp_out.insert(omp_out.end(), omp_in.begin(), omp_in.end()))
#pragma omp parallel for collapse(2) schedule(dynamic,1) reduction(mergeFindAffineShapeArgs : findAffineShapeArgs)
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
   v.push_back(//something);
}
```

In few words, the reduction operation appends each local version of `v` to the global one.

I've never used TBB before, but I've read [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506117), [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506063) and [this](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506154?language=en) tutorial, but I don't even understand if this is even possible in TBB.

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: it is absolutely possible, the difference is that you might want to reduce partial vectors, not the global one. If you want reduction on global, you don't need `parallel_reduce`, but use `parallel_for` with global variable protected by a lock. Or, which is more efficient, use  `tbb::combinable`

Comment: @Anton thanks for your comment. Could you please explain better the point of reduction of partial vector? Do you know any code where this case is explained also with tbb::comparable?